# How to disable/enable user accout in openLDAP?

Tags: java, openldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

In our application we implemented directory authentication service. i.e - Active directory or OpenLDAP. Using directory credential user can access all services of our application. But if any user disable in directory, this user not able to access any services of our application. But in openLDAP there is not any option for disable/enable user. so how to disable and enable user in open ldap and which user property can I access for identify user is disable or not? We are  using unboundid-ldap-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Password policy overlay](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-ppolicy&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.3-Release), which you should be using anyway, and set the `pwdAccountLockedTime` to `000001010000Z` as described in the link.